# Why Base Class catch block catch derived class object?

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance

Why does the `Base` `catch` handler catch a `Derived` object, as in:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {};
class Derived: public Base {};

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   try {
        throw d;
   }    
   catch(Base b)
   {
        cout << "Caught Base Exception";
   }    
   catch(...)
   {
       cout << "Default\n";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The output I get is "Caught Base Exception". I was expecting "Default".

Comment: Note that you are slicing the object at the same time as catching it. To avoid this, catch by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Because a `Derived` is implicitly convertible to a `Base`, so when the first `catch` handler is tried, it succeeds. This is the same reason why we can call all the `std` exceptions as:

```
catch (std::exception const& e) {
   ..
}
```

Otherwise, we would have to enumerate all of them - which would be tedious at best and impossible at worst.

Answer (score 2):

Catch clauses are evaluated in the order in which they are listed. A search for a viable catch clause stops when a catch clause parameter satisfies some prerequisite corresponding to the throw expression:

> When an exception of type `E` is thrown by any statement in *compound-statement*, it is matched against the types of the formal parameters `T` of each *catch-clause* in *handler-seq*, **in the order in which the catch clauses are listed**. The exception is a match if any of the following is true:
>
> - `E` and `T` are the same type (ignoring top-level cv-qualifiers on `T`)
> - `T` is an lvalue-reference to (possibly cv-qualified) `E`
> - **`T` is an unambiguous public base class of `E`**
> - […]

`Base` is an unambiguous base of `Derived`, so the first catch block is chosen. Since a *catch-all* handler (`catch(...)`) can only appear last in the list of catch handlers, it is the least viable candidate for a catch handler.

Answer (score 0):

Think it as this.

```
Derived* d = new Derived;
Base* b = d;
```

This valid, since a parent class reference variable can point to a child class object. And the type from `Derived` to `Base` is automatically cast (implicit casting).

It's the same scenario in the `try-catch` block.

You throw a `Derived` object (referebce). It can be caught from a `Derived` reference **or a predecessor reference**.

Ideally, the `try-catch` should look like this.

```
   Derived d;
   try {
        throw d;
   }    
   catch(Derived d)
   {
        cout << "Caught Derived Exception";
   }    
   catch(Base b)
   {
       cout << "Caught Base Exception";
       // This will catch any other references which extends Base as well.
   }
   catch(...)
   {
       cout << "Default\n";
   }
   return 0;
```

Interchanging 1st and 2nd catch clauses may cause unexpected behavior.