# Why is this exact exception thrown in my c++ code?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I am analyzing part of code that was part of my lectures.
I have managed to compile it but I cannot understand:
why does my program output "Wyjatek" and 0 instead of "WyjatekNieoznaczony"?

I was pretty sure WyjatekNieoznaczony() should be thrown because a=0 and b=0 as well. Right now i am a little bit confused. 
Could you help me, please?

```
class Wyjatek {};
class WyjatekBledny : public Wyjatek {};
class WyjatekNieoznaczony : public Wyjatek {};

double f(double a, double b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        if (a == 0)
            throw WyjatekNieoznaczony();
        else
            throw WyjatekBledny();
    }
    return a / b;
}


double g(double a, double b) throw (int) {
    try {
        return f(a, b);
    }
    catch (WyjatekBledny) {
        cout << "Wyjatek bledny" << endl;
        throw 1;
    }
    catch (Wyjatek) {
        cout << "Wyjatek" << endl;
    }
    catch (WyjatekNieoznaczony) {
        cout << "Wyjatek nieoznaczony" << endl;
        throw;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    double a = 0, b = 0;
    try {
        cout << g(a, b) << endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Inny wyjatek" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `catch` statements work from top to bottom. If an exception can be caught by a given `catch`, it will be and the rest of them will be ignored. Since `WyjątekNieoznaczony` is also a `Wyjatek`, only the second catch will be executed. I'm looking for a duplicate of this.

Comment: Closest question to yours I could find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731033/why-base-class-catch-block-catch-derived-class-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ exception handling in class hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575307/c-exception-handling-in-class-hierarchies)

Comment: A side note: coding in English is a good practice. It will help you a lot later, when for example you need to ask another question on StackOverflow. Not all of us know  Polish ;)

Comment: I will keep that in mind while posting in the future :)

Comment: Please add proper indentation to your post so that we can easily follow your code.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Close as dupe or don't close as dupe but please do not give the answer in the comments section. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes indeed a `WyjatekNieoznaczony` is thrown, but at the catch site, `catch (Wyjatek) {` is a match (due to the inheritance) so it's caught there.

A catch site is more like an `if` `else` block in behaviour - with each `catch` possibility being considered in the order they are written - rather than a `switch` block where you can put the labels in any order you like.

Note also that it's a good idea to catch exceptions by `const` reference than by value, else you can suffer the pitfalls of *object slicing*.

Comment: Thank you very much! This code was supposed to be tricky for students I guess. I will keep your advice at mind!

Comment: Catching by value also defeats the purpose of memory being reserved for exceptions ahead of time (though that's not particularly important unless the exception you catch was thrown due to a memory shortage). Or ... is such a copy elided? Hmm

Answer (score 3):

If you enabled (and read) compiler warnings, you would've encountered the following diagnostic:

> warning: exception of type 'WyjatekNieoznaczony' will be caught [...] by earlier handler for 'Wyjatek'.

This basically means that `WyjatekNieoznaczony`, by inheriting from `Wyjatek`, will be first caught by `catch(Wyjatek)` clause, since it's convertible. The problem is that due to [*object slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing), it will lose its `Nieoznaczony`ness.

What I suggest is to reorder the `catch` clauses so the possibility of slicing disappears (in this case):

```
catch (WyjatekBledny) {
    cout << "Wyjatek bledny" << endl;
    throw 1;
}
catch (WyjatekNieoznaczony) {
    cout << "Wyjatek nieoznaczony" << endl;
    throw;
}
catch (Wyjatek) {
    cout << "Wyjatek" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I am aware that I was caused by inheritance and I understand it.

Comment: @SzymonRuciński, no problem! However I advise you to look into [Bathsheba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56835518/7151494) too and apply the `catch`ing by `const&` rather than by value. Furthermore, if the answer solved your issue, I suggest accepting it so the future visitors will know that it indeed is the solution.